# How do i parse a text file

Tags: python, parsing, text

My instruction book tells me i can parse my .txt file by  tabs, but when i try  run  the  code the book e gave me, Python doesn't like how I parse. I also try .split on ',' that didn't' I dont seem to be accessing the particular columns that I separate with a tab or ','. I  read the whole line I do. but I was to separate line, line [0] and line[1] see my code below.

```
from ingredients import Ingredient
from inventory import Inventory


def main():
    f = open('food_inv_new.txt')
    lines = f.readlines()
    items = {}
for line in lines:
    line = line.strip('\n')
    line = line.strip('\t')
    item = Ingredient(title=line[0])
    items[item] = line[1]
inventory = Inventory(items)
inventory.print_inventory()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

''' from Inventory class '''
def print_inventory(self):
    for item in self.items:
        print item, "-", self.items[item]

''' from Ingredient class '''
def __init__(self, title, description=''):
    self.title = title
    self.description = description

def  __str__(self):
    return self.title
''' In the .txt file: title is the first field(name of Item)
   description is the number of inventory

'''
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Can you show `lines` after you do `readlines`? You remove tabs before splitting, maybe this is an issue. But I can just guess without seeing your input.

Comment: My output ['eggs\t48\n', 'flour(lbs)\t25\n', 'mozz cheese\t10\n', 'tomato sauce\t15\n', 'milk(gal)\t10']
t - o (line0)
m - o (line1)
m - I(line2)
f - l(line3)
e - g(line4)

Comment: I should get the Item  and quantity for each line . I.e. Eggs      12

Comment: What I don't understand is. line[0] is the first character in the line,  instead of being the first value delimited by \t or ','.  line[1] is the second character in the line  instead of being the second  value delimited by \t or ','.  could I specify the length of the field ill the next \t in the line? @Dschoni

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to answer with the minimum an information you were giving.

If your file looks like

```
lines = ['eggs\t48\n', 'flour(lbs)\t25\n', 'mozz cheese\t10\n', 'tomato sauce\t15\n', 'milk(gal)\t10']
```

is a list with 5 entries.

Now, you create a dictionary:

```
items = {}
```

and iterate through the list:

```
for line in lines:
  line = line.rstrip('\n') # Removing only the newline symbol
  split_item = line.split('\t') #Splitting at the '\t'
  items[split_item[0]]=split_item[1] #Setting the dictionary entry
```

Your output will be a dictionary:

```
items = {'eggs':'48', 'flour(lbs)':'25', ...}
```

Note that the values will be strings, where you probably want to have integers. You can do a simple typecast to change that if needed.

Comment: thanks Dschoni.. That makes sense.. before anyone yells at me again for putting it in the wrong place. or they think it was previously solved.